# Lookup table with fixed array

Tags: c, lookup

I implemented the following excercise:

> Implement a lookup table with operations such as `find(struct table*, const char*)`, `insert(struct table*, const char*,int)`, and `remove(struct table*, const char*)`. The representation of the table could be an array of a `struct` pair or a pair of arrays (`const char*[]` and `int*`); you choose, also choose return types for your functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 10

struct Pair {
    const char* word;
    int val;
};

struct Table {
    struct Pair* pairs[ARR_SIZE];
    size_t sz;
};

struct Pair* make_pair(const char* word, int val)
{
    assert(word);

    struct Pair* pair = (struct Pair*)malloc(sizeof(struct Pair));
    pair->val = val;
    pair->word = word;

    return pair;
}

void table_empty(struct Table* tbl)
 {
    assert(tbl);

    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tbl->sz; ++i) {
        free(tbl->pairs[i]);
        tbl->pairs[i] = NULL;
    }
    tbl->sz = 0;
}

int search_word(struct Table* tbl, const char* word)
{
    assert(tbl);
    assert(word);

    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tbl->sz; ++i) {

        //printf("%s %i\n", tbl->pairs[i]->word,i);

        if (strcmp(tbl->pairs[i]->word, word) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;  // error
}

void table_insert(struct Table* tbl, const char* word, int val)
{
    assert(tbl);
    assert(word);

    int i = search_word(tbl, word);
    if (i != -1) {          // replace val

        tbl->pairs[i]->val = val;   
    }
    else {                                          // add new pair
        struct Pair* pair = make_pair(word, val);

        tbl->pairs[tbl->sz] = pair; // add pair at the last position
        ++tbl->sz;
    }
}

int table_find(struct Table* tbl, const char* word, int* return_val)
{
    assert(tbl);
    assert(word);
    assert(return_val);

    int i = search_word(tbl, word);

    if (i != -1) {
        *return_val = tbl->pairs[i]->val;
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;      // error not found
}

int table_remove(struct Table* tbl, const char* word)
{
    assert(tbl);
    assert(word);

    int i = search_word(tbl, word);

    if (i == -1) return -1;

    free(tbl->pairs[i]);        // free value at current pos

    tbl->pairs[i] = tbl->pairs[tbl->sz - 1];        // put address of last word at the pos of the current
    --tbl->sz;  // "erase" last word

    return 0;
}

void table_print(struct Table* tbl)
{
    assert(tbl);

    printf("\n");
    printf("table size = %i\n", tbl->sz);

    for (int i = 0; i < tbl->sz; ++i)
        printf("%s %i\n", tbl->pairs[i]->word, tbl->pairs[i]->val);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void print_search_result(struct Table* tbl, const char* word)
{
    assert(tbl);
    assert(word);

    int val = 0;

    if (table_find(tbl, word, &val) == 0) 
        printf("%s %i\n",word, val);
    else 
        printf("%s not found in table\n", word);
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void print_remove_result(struct Table* tbl, const char* word)
{
    assert(tbl);
    assert(word);

    if (table_remove(tbl, word) == -1) 
        printf("%s not deleted\n", word);
    else 
        printf("%s deleted\n", word);
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main()
{
    struct Table table = { 0 };
    int val = 0;

    table_insert(&table, "Hello", 10);
    table_insert(&table, "Test", 15);
    table_insert(&table, "Hello", 18);      // testing overrite val
    table_insert(&table, "What", 5);
    table_insert(&table, "is", 3);
    table_insert(&table, "going", 4);
    table_insert(&table, "on", 77);

    table_print(&table);

    print_search_result(&table, "Hello");
    print_search_result(&table, "Test");
    print_search_result(&table, "keyword");

    print_remove_result(&table, "Hello");
    print_remove_result(&table, "Hello");       // double delete == false
    print_remove_result(&table, "What");
    print_remove_result(&table, "going");
    print_remove_result(&table, "is");
    print_remove_result(&table, "on");
    print_remove_result(&table, "Test");

    table_print(&table);    

    table_insert(&table, "Hello", 10);
    table_insert(&table, "Test", 15);
    table_insert(&table, "Hello", 18);      // testing overrite val
    table_insert(&table, "What", 5);
    table_insert(&table, "is", 3);
    table_insert(&table, "going", 4);
    table_insert(&table, "on", 77);

    table_print(&table);

    table_empty(&table);

    table_print(&table);

    getchar();
}
```

Feel free to comment on any improvements. Is there a better way to do this?

I have one specific question also: are my uses of `assert` appropriate?

Comment: As a stylistic nitpick, I'd recommend the `*` in a pointer type be adjacent to the variable name (e.g. `const char *word`). The C type syntax was designed to mimic usage, where for example you'd type `*word` to access a `const char` element. Note also that this makes it more clear what type `b` is in `int *a, b;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using `struct`

Personally, I think you made the right choice by using a `struct` with a `char*` and `int` in it rather than 2 arrays of `char*` and `int`, respectively. The `Pair` is a conceptual unit of data in your app, so it makes sense to put them together.  If you had 2 separate arrays, it would be easy for them to get out of synch and hard to debug why that happened. Nice work!

## Prefer `const` and functions to macros

You've defined the array size using a macro. <s>This puts you at a disadvantage while programming. You've removed the type information for the value. By making it:</s>

```
const int ARR_SIZE = 10;
```

you get type safety. **Edit:** That's a C++-ism that doesn't work in C. My bad! But the rest of the advice in the next paragraph is correct as far as I know.

With macros that take parameters you run the risk of them being used in unexpected ways and causing hard to debug issues. Luckily, you haven't done that here. But in general, if you find yourself reaching for a macro, ask yourself if you would be better off with a constant or a function. You almost always will be (assuming you can use the constant in the desired way).

## Errors

There are some errors in your code. In `make_pair()`, you don't check to see if `malloc()` succeeded. If it fails, no memory is allocated, and `pair` points to `NULL`. When you try to assign `pair->val` or `pair->word` you will crash.

If you did fix that, `table_insert()` uses the result of `make_pair()` without checking to see if it's `NULL` first. This won't crash immediately, because you're just assigning the array pointer in `tbl->pairs[tbl->sz]` to have the value of `pair`. What will happen is later when you try to search or print or insert another item, you'll get a crash when you iterate over that entry in the table and try to do anything with it.

You could make these errors not possible by not dynamically allocating the array entries. Simply make the array an array of `Pair` structs rather than a pointer to them.

## Naming

A lot of your names are really good. `Pair` and `Table` are decent, readable names for this task. `make_pair()`, `table_insert()`, etc. are informative. Some could be improved, though. `tbl` does not save you much typing over `table`. Just use the whole word. Same with `sz` vs. `size`. `i` is acceptable as a loop variable name, but it would be even better if it was more descriptive. For example, `entry_index` or `pair_index`. It should describe what you're iterating over.

Comment: when i change the define to   `const int ARR_SIZE = 10;`  it gives me an error in `struct Table {
 struct Pair* pairs[ARR_SIZE];
 size_t sz;
};` that ARR_SIZE is not const, So how to use it in this case then?

Comment: Sorry - that's a C++-ism. I thought this was a C++ question. My bad. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm a staunch supporter of descriptive variable names, but with the simplicity of the loops in this program I think the variable name `i` works just fine.

Comment: If `malloc()` fails, assigning to `pair->val` or `pair->word` *might* crash, **if you are lucky**.  It might just continue and give wrong results, or it might do something totally unexpected.  That's the joy of Undefined Behaviour!

Answer (score 4):

- Do not cast the result of `malloc`.

  `malloc` returns `void *`, and in C it is valid to convert `void *` to any pointer. If you cast to suppress a warning about integer to pointer conversion, it means that a compiler doesn't have a `malloc` prototype, and defaults its to return an `int` (it is an ancient C convention). Now if `int` and pointer are of different size, the malloc return value would be truncated, with all nasty consequences.
- It is not recommended to `sizeof(type)`. Prefer `sizeof(expression)`. In your case, consider

  ```
      struct Pair * pair = malloc(sizeof(*pair));
  ```
- `table_insert` blindly inserts into a full table. It should test for `tbl->sz < ARR_SIZE` and return an error indication if it is not.
- The actual insertion

  ```
      struct Pair* pair = make_pair(word, val);

      tbl->pairs[tbl->sz] = pair; // add pair at the last position
  ```

  should be really a single line:

  ```
      tbl->pairs[tbl->sz] = make_pair(word, val);
  ```

Comment: why is it not a good idea to cast malloc? In c++ it even would get a compiler error?

Comment: @Sandro4912 The question is tagged C. C++ is a different language, particularly in this respect. Now if the C compiler complains, it means that the `malloc` prototype is missing, which may lead to nasty problems.

Comment: yes i know is c. i was just wondered why here its not a good practice to indicate the type changes with a cast

Comment: @Sandro4912 See edit.

Comment: @Sandro4912 `pair = malloc(sizeof *pair)` is easier to code correctly the first time, easier to review and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

### Enable all compiler warnings

With a well enabled compiler, `for (int i = 0; i < tbl->sz; ++i)` should have warned about mixing sign-ness of `i` and `tbl->sz` as well as range.  Save time and enable all warnings and use `for (size_t i = 0; i < tbl->sz; ++i)`.

In general, code is squishy on using `int,size_t` nearly interchangeably.  I'd re-architect and use `size_t` only.

### Mixed use of shallow and deep copy

`make_pair(const char* word, int val)` allocates and forms a whole new `struct Pair` (deep copy), yet does not copy what `word` points to.

Perhaps

```
// pair->word = word;
pair->word = strdup(word);
```

### Use `const`

`search_word()` does not modify `*tbl`, so use `const to convey that.  Same for`table_find()`,`table_print()`,`print_search_result()`.

```
// int search_word(struct Table* tbl, const char* word)
int search_word(const struct Table* tbl, const char* word)
```

### Naming

Code uses `const char* word;` yet it is not a "word", but a *string* as used in `strcmp()`.

----- Additions

### Contract violation?

Nothing in the requirements "Implement a lookup table with operations such as ..." indicate that `const char*` is a pointer to a *string*.  So calling `strcmp()` is questionable unless unstated requirements exist.  As a `char *`, code could use a simple compare

```
// if (strcmp(tbl->pairs[i]->word, word) == 0)
if (tbl->pairs[i]->word == word)
```

### Use of `assert()`

> are my uses of assert appropriate?

If the `char *` pointer to add/search is not specified to be a *string*, `assert(word);` is not proper as `word == NULL` is not known to be invalid.

The `assert(return_val)` in `table_find(struct Table* tbl, const char* word, int* return_val)` is OK, yet I would re-design to allow `return_val == NULL`

```
if (i != -1) {
    // add
    if (return_val) {
      *return_val = tbl->pairs[i]->val;
    }  
    return 0;
}
```